# MySql Sum If conditions are met with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have 2 Tables:
"Trades_Imported"

```
Id  TradeId       Price  OrderType   
1   01-01-20 ABC  525    B
2   01-01-20 ABC  275    S
3   01-01-20 ABC  288    S
```

and "Trades_Grouped"

```
TradeId       EntryPrice  ExitPrice
01-01-20 ABC  525         563 (SUM of all Sales Order of TradeId)
```

I do not know how I can say: 
EntryPrice = Sum (Price) if OrderType = B; 
ExitPrice = Sum (Price) if OrderType = S;
because I am already Grouping by TradeId ... any ideas? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance (I am using MySql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select tradeid,
    sum(price) sum_price,
    sum(case when ordertype = 'B' then price else 0 end) sum_price_b,
    sum(case when ordertype = 'S' then price else 0 end) sum_price_s
from trades_imported
group by tradeid
```